# Do the G5 countries have veto right in the UNODC?

Tags: united-nations, veto

I cannot find good sources online. Am i looking wrong?

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr:** No, they don't.

The United Nations Office on Drugs and Crime is an executive organ of the United Nations. As such it is lead by an executive director ([currently Yuri Fedotov](http://www.unodc.org/unodc/en/eds-corner/biography.html)) who is appointed by the secretary general of the United Nations.

This means the UNODC is only directly accountable to the UN General-Secretary Ban Ki-moon.

If any UN membership countries (G5 or not) are unhappy about the UNODC, they can:

- Ask the UN general secretary (nicely!) to reprimand the current executive director or replace him. The general secretary is not obligated to do this, though.
- Cut their [funding](http://www.unodc.org/unodc/en/donors/index.html?ref=menuside). The UNODC is a voluntary program where each UN state can decide if and how much they want to contribute. Contributions can be earmarked, so states can decide to not contribute to any UNODC activities they disagree with.
- Forbid the UNODC from operating within their territory (if they have signed any [treaties](http://www.unodc.org/unodc/en/treaties/index.html?ref=menuside) which explicitly allow this, they would have to cancel those treaties first)
- Propose a UN resolution to disband it and hope it finds a majority.

Comment: Would that be a UNGA resolution to disband it?